Using Outlet on my protected route is showing a black page
I'm working with React and updated my app to use an overall layout.
There are public routes and protected routes.
When I changed the code from using children to <Outlet> I'm seeing a black page on when I navigate to any of my protected routes.
I've debugged for a bit now and I cannot figure it out.
It wills how the "Loading Protected Route"... really quick and then goes black.
Any ideas what it could be?
My understanding is I need to use <Outlet> instead of children
I even tried to return only return <Outlet/>; and it still shows black.
Here is my setup:
import Admin from "./restricted/Admin";

import { AuthProvider, Logout, APIProvider, ToastProvider, ErrorPage, ErrorBoundaryRouter, ProtectedRoute } from "@app/Shared"
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

import HomePage from "./home/Home";
import Layout from "./layouts/Layout";

function App() {
  return (
    <ErrorBoundaryRouter fallbackUrl="/ErrorPage">
    <AuthProvider>
      <APIProvider>
        <ToastProvider>
        <Routes>
          {/* All routes share the Layout */}
          <Route element={<Layout />}>
              {/* Public Routes */}
              <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
              <Route path="/public" element={<Public/>} />
            {/* Error Route */}
            <Route path="/Error/:message" element={<ErrorPage />} />
            
            {/* Protected Routes */}
            <Route element={<ProtectedRoute/>}>
              <Route path="/admin" element={<Admin />} />
              <Route path="/userUpdate" element={<userUpdate />} />
              <Route path="/logout" element={<Logout />} />
            </Route> 
          </Route>
        </Routes>
        </ToastProvider>
      </APIProvider>
    </AuthProvider>  
    </ErrorBoundaryRouter>  
  );
}
export default App;

Here is the Protected Route:
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useAuth } from "./useAuth";
import { userServer } from "../api/userServer";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";


export const ProtectedRoute = () => {
  const { user, fetchUserClaims } = useAuth();
  const userAPI = userServer();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkAuthentication = async () => {
      try {
        const isLoggedIn = await userAPI.getUserLoggedInStatus();
        if (!isLoggedIn) {
          window.location.href = "/"; // Redirect to home if not logged in
        } else if (!user) {
          await fetchUserClaims();
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error during authentication check:", error);
        window.location.href = "/"; // Redirect to home on error
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    checkAuthentication();
  }, [user]);

  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading Protected Content...</div>;
  }

  return user && user.isLoggedIn ? <Outlet/>: null;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;

Here is my Layout:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { TopToolbar, useAuth, isAuthenticated } from "@app/shared";
import { CardItem, getCardItems } from "../home/cardItems";

const Layout: React.FC = () => {
  const { logout, fetchUserClaims } = useAuth();

  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState<{ firstName: string; lastName: string } | null>(null);
  const [initials, setInitials] = useState<string>("?");
  const [cardItems, setCardItems] = useState<CardItem[]>([]);

  // Helper function to calculate initials
  const calculateInitials = (firstName?: string, lastName?: string) => {
    if (firstName && lastName) {
      return `${firstName.charAt(0)}${lastName.charAt(0)}`.toUpperCase();
    }
    return "?";
  };

  // Fetch user data and determine card items
  const checkAuthentication = async () => {
    try {
      const loggedInStatus = await isAuthenticated();
      setIsLoggedIn(loggedInStatus);

      if (loggedInStatus) {
        const claims = await fetchUserClaims();
        if (claims) {
          setUserData({ firstName: claims.firstName, lastName: claims.lastName });
          setInitials(calculateInitials(claims.firstName, claims.lastName));
          setCardItems(getCardItems(true)); // Get logged-in card items
        }
      } else {
        setUserData(null);
        setInitials("?");
        setCardItems(getCardItems(false)); // Get guest card items
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setIsLoggedIn(false);
      setUserData(null);
      setInitials("?");
      setCardItems(getCardItems(false)); // Fallback for unauthenticated state
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkAuthentication();
  }, []);

  const handleLogout = () => {
    logout();
    setIsLoggedIn(false);
    setUserData(null);
    setInitials("?");
    setCardItems(getCardItems(false));
  };

  return (
    <div className="h-screen flex flex-col">
      {/* Top Toolbar */}
      <div>
        <TopToolbar
          userInitials={initials}
          firstName={userData?.firstName || "Guest"}
          lastName={userData?.lastName || ""}
          onLogout={isLoggedIn ? handleLogout : () => {}}
          allowToggleMenu={isLoggedIn}
        />
      </div>

      {/* Main Content */}
      <main className="flex-grow overflow-auto">
        {/* Provide cardItems via Outlet context */}
        <Outlet context={{ cardItems }} />
      </main>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Layout;


Here is main:
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.tsx'
import './index.css'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { registerLicense } from '@syncfusion/ej2-base'

registerLicense(window._env_.VITE_SYNCFUSION_LICENSE_KEY)

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
)


Consuming app package.json
"dependencies": {
    "@syncfusion/ej2": "~27.2.2",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-base": "~27.2.2",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-data": "~27.2.2",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-buttons": "~27.2.2",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-dropdowns": "~26.1.38",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-grids": "~27.2.2",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-inputs": "~27.2.2",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-layouts": "~27.2.2",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-navigations": "~27.2.2",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-notifications": "~27.2.2",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-pdfviewer": "~27.2.3",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-popups": "~27.2.2",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-querybuilder": "~27.2.2",
    "dotenv": "~16.4.5",
    "immer": "~10.0.4",
    "react": "~18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "~18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "~7.0.1",
    "remark-rehype": "^11.1.1",
    "use-immer": "~0.9.0",
    "uuid": "~9.0.1",
    "zustand": "~4.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "~20.12.7",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.79",
    "@types/react-dom": "~18.2.25",
    "@types/uuid": "~9.0.8",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~7.7.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "~7.7.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-basic-ssl": "~1.1.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "~4.3.3",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "~3.6.0",
    "autoprefixer": "~10.4.19",
    "concurrently": "~8.2.2",
    "eslint": "~8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "~4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "~0.4.6",
    "postcss": "~8.4.38",
    "tailwindcss": "~3.4.3",
    "typescript": "~5.4.5",
    "vite": "~5.2.10"
  }

Shared Lib dependencies
  "dependencies": {
    "@syncfusion/ej2-popups": "~27.2.2",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-buttons": "~27.2.2",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-dropdowns": "~27.2.2",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-notifications": "27.2.2",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-popups": "~27.2.2",
    "dompurify": "^3.2.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^7.0.1",
    "rehype-stringify": "^10.0.1",
    "remark": "^15.0.1",
    "remark-parse": "^11.0.0",
    "remark-rehype": "^11.1.1",
    "unified": "^11.0.5",
    "uuid": "~9.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^22.9.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.12",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "@types/uuid": "~9.0.8",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "chokidar-cli": "^3.0.0",
    "cpx": "^1.5.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "rimraf": "^6.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.14",
    "typescript": "^5.6.3",
    "vite": "^5.4.11"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "~7.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3"
  }


What is the value of user.isLoggedIn in your protected route component? I suspect it is falsey and ProtectedRoute returns null, e.g. the "blank page". What does useAuth do? Please include a more complete [mcve].

@DrewReese: Even if I set the ProtectedRoute to return the <Outlet> only, it still goes to black, so I do not believe that is any of the issue.  I can try to do another example in time, if I can't figure it out.

So what debugging investigation have you done? What are the values of user and user.isLoggedIn in ProtectedRoute? What is rendered to the DOM? You can check this using the inspect tool in the browser's dev-tools. Are there any errors in the console? What are the exact reproduction steps to produce the issue? I think we need more detail here since I don't see any overt issues in the code you have shared.

@DrewReese: I moved the ProtectedRoute from my shared library back to my consuming app and it works? Not sure what the shared library has to do with the ProtectedRoute not working with <Outlet>? I assume that when I was using {children} before, it didn't matter? Any thoughts? The authentication and db calls seemed to be fine the entire time, ie, I could show that I was logged in via console, logs, but as soon as it hit the <Outlet> it wouldn't work and show black.

It should not have ever worked rendering children instead of Outlet because ProtectedRoute is a layout route component, not a wrapper component, e.g. it doesn't directly wrap and render any children components. As for why moving it from your shared library I suspect that maybe it was built using a separate instance of react-router-dom where it just doesn't see this app's routing context. This is just a guess though. Can you clarify what you mean by "my shared library" though?

@DrewReese: Yes, so I am saving certain components in the "shared library", so that we can reuse them in other applications. Alot of the Auth stuff is in there and so far has worked. Also ProtectedRoute worked before I moved it. I'm using pnpm workspace to connected the shared library to my consuming app. You might be right, something with the react-router-dom could be the issue.

I believe I have it figured out:
We use Vite for our Shared Library.
In my vite config, I had set the rollupOptions for external for 'react-router-dom'
After I did that, I was able to use my ProtectedRoute component in my consuming app and let it live in the shared library.
Now I can use the same ProtectedRoute for other apps.
 rollupOptions: {
        external: ['react', 'react-dom', 'react-router-dom', 'tailwindcss'],

Full code:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import path from 'path';
import { exec } from 'child_process';

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  const isDevelopment = mode === 'development';
  console.log('Vite mode:', mode);
  console.log('isDevelopment:', isDevelopment);
  
  return {
    plugins: [
      react(),
      {
        name: 'copy-dts-after-build',
        buildEnd() {
          if (isDevelopment) {
            // This command will run after Vite finishes the build in development mode
            exec('npm run copy:types', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
              if (err) {
                console.error(`Error copying .d.ts files: ${stderr}`);
              } else {
                console.log(`.d.ts files copied successfully: ${stdout}`);
              }
            });
          }
        },
      },
    ],
    build: {
      sourcemap: isDevelopment,  // Enable sourcemaps only during development
      minify: !isDevelopment,    // Turn off minification during development
      watch: isDevelopment
        ? {
            include: 'src/**',
          }
        : undefined,
      lib: {
        entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.ts'),
        name: 'platform-react-shared-frontend',
        formats: ['es', 'cjs'],
        fileName: (format) => `platform-react-shared-frontend.${format}.js`,
      },
      outDir: 'dist',
      emptyOutDir: false,
      rollupOptions: {
        external: ['react', 'react-dom', 'react-router-dom', 'tailwindcss'],
        output: {
          dir: 'dist',
        },
      },
    },
  };
});



The issue you are facing (black screen) could arise if the loading state doesn't resolve as expected or if the user is not correctly authenticated.
so try to update your code like below :
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useAuth } from "./useAuth";
import { userServer } from "../api/userServer";
import { Outlet, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

export const ProtectedRoute = () => {
  const { user, fetchUserClaims } = useAuth();
  const userAPI = userServer();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkAuthentication = async () => {
      try {
        const isLoggedIn = await userAPI.getUserLoggedInStatus();
        if (!isLoggedIn) {
          setLoading(false);  // Stop loading and redirect
        } else if (!user) {
          await fetchUserClaims();
        } else {
          setLoading(false);  // User data is loaded, stop loading
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error during authentication check:", error);
        setLoading(false);  // Stop loading even on error
      }
    };

    checkAuthentication();
  }, [user, fetchUserClaims, userAPI]);

  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading Protected Content...</div>;  // Loading state
  }

  if (!user || !user.isLoggedIn) {
    return <Navigate to="/" />;  // Redirect to home if not authenticated
  }

  return <Outlet />;  // Render protected content if authenticated
};

export default ProtectedRoute;


Explanation : Instead of using window.location.href, we now use Navigate from react-router-dom to redirect the user when not authenticated or on error. This ensures a clean redirect without page reloads and works seamlessly with React Router.


The loading state is only set to false once the user authentication check is complete. This prevents rendering the Outlet before it's ready.

If there is an error during the authentication check, we ensure that the loading state is updated and we stop further rendering or redirect accordingly.

If the user is not authenticated or the user.isLoggedIn is false, the user is redirected to the home page. Otherwise, it renders the Outlet (the protected route).



Look at my comment on my main => I moved the ProtectedRoute from my shared library back to my consuming app and it works? Not sure what the shared library has to do with the ProtectedRoute not working with <Outlet>? I assume that when I was using {children} before, it didn't matter? Any thoughts? The authentication and db calls seemed to be fine the entire time, ie, I could show that I was logged in via console, logs, but as soon as it hit the <Outlet> it wouldn't work and show black.
